# MySQL update join not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, join, transactions, sql-update

I'm using MySQL 5.1.41 on ubuntu 12.10 and MySQL Workbench.

I have 2 product tables, t1 and t2. t1 is the live data and t2 is a imported data ready to be updated into t1 to update all the new product prices. So I run:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.price != t2.price;
```

This returns 1201 records where the price is different and needs to be updated. So I run:

```
UPDATE t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.price = t2.price
WHERE t1.price != t2.price;
```

This completes without error and reports 1143 row(s) affected, Rows matched: 1143  Changed: 1143  Warnings: 0

So already something here is not right. 1201 records were different in the select query, but only 1143 changed using the same join and criteria?

Running the initial select query I'd expect to see 58 records that still had different prices. But when running it I get the same 1201 as I did initially. It's as if the updates are not being committed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Both table entrie has the same Ids?

Comment: Are both `t1.price` and `t2.price` columns of the same type?

Comment: What sllev means (I think) is: Are the `id` primary keys in both tables? If not, that's the reason.

Comment: yes both id columns are PK and same data type

Comment: sorry, i just double checked and t2.id is not PK or UNIQUE and contains duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number (`1201`) that your `SELECT` shows is not records of `t1` but rows from the `JOIN` of two tables. If the two `id` are not both `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY`s then this is expected. Some rows of `t1` match multiple rows from `t2`. But when the `UPDATE` is done they are only updated once (this is a MySQL "feature" or "bug" of `UPDATE` that checks `WHERE` conditions sequentially during an update statement.

Try this to see how many rows (of `t1`) should be updated:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM t2
        WHERE t1.id = t2.id
          AND t1.price != t2.price
      );
```

Comment: But `JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id`

Comment: @Tomalak: I assume that despite being called `id`s, one of them is not UNIQUE. Is there any other possible explanation?

Comment: I see now that both are PKs. So I'm more confused, And further, the OP's details that `Rows matched: 1143 Changed: 1143` is shown but updates seem to not be committed is even more confusing.

Comment: Why would you assume that o.O

Comment: @ypercube You're right. My t2.id is not set to UNIQUE and also i've found that t2 contains duplicates. The source CSV also contains these duplicates id's so I'm just fixing my import script to handle that, then add UNIQUE constraint and it should be good to go.